# "git remote add origin" just shows the usage for "git remote add"

Tags: git

I have a local repository on my laptop's hard drive, running Windows 7, and I'd like to set up a remote repository on a shared network drive.  On the shared network drive, I have created a folder `thisProject.git` and created a bare repository there using `git init --bare`.  I have tried to set the remote as follows:

```
git remote add origin file://\\some.site.com\projects\fldr\Software Development\Git\thisProject.git
```

But this only gives me the response:

```
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
```

etc., which seems to indicate that I formatted the `git remote add` command incorrectly or there's something wrong with the path.

I tried it with the mapped network drive version of the path as well:

```
git remote add origin file://u:\Software Development\Git\thisProject.git
```

This got the same response.

How should I add the remote if it's on a network drive like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Carefully check what you were trying to execute:

```
git remote add origin file://\\some.site.com\projects\fldr\Software Development\Git\thisProject.git
```

...and what's the actual usage:

```
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>
```

Count number of arguments in your command and the usage.

Except of `git remote add` (and `<options>` you're not using) you should pass **2** arguments: `<name>` and `<url>`, but you're actually passing **3** arguments:

- `origin`
- `file://\\some.site.com\projects\fldr\Software`
- `Development\Git\thisProject.git`

You have to change it so you're passing only 2 arguments to the `git`. You can do it simply by enclosing the `<url>` argument by (double)quotes:

```
git remote add origin "file://\\some.site.com\projects\fldr\Software Development\Git\thisProject.git"
```

It's completely logical behavior - **commands and arguments are delimited by the <kbd>space</kbd> character, so any single argument containing such character has to be enclosed by (double)quotes**.